# Заполнить массив, как показано на рисунке (решить для массивов NxN. )

Tags: java, массивы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня пока что получилось заполнить только `i[0] i[1]` и `j[0] j[1]`, то есть только две строки и два столбца. Вот код:

```
    private static final int ROWS = 6;
    private static final int COLUMN = 6;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            show(deepArray1());

        }

        private static int[][] deepArray1(){
            int[][] arrays = new int[ROWS][COLUMN];
            int x = 1;
            int y = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++) {
                    if (i == 0 || j == 0){
                        arrays[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                    if (i == 1){
                        arrays[i][j] = x++;
                    }
                    if (j == 1){
                        arrays[i][j] = y++;
                    }

                }
            }
            return arrays;
        }

private static void show(int[][] arrays){
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + arrays[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Дальше я понимаю, что ячейка `[2] [2]` заполняется значением полученным суммой ячеек `[2][1] + [1][2]` и последующие ячейки заполняются по такому принципу. При этом длина массива уже будет равняться `(COLUMN / 3) * 2`, то есть две трети от первоначальной длины. А вот как это прописать в коде, ни как не соображу. Помогите добить эту часть задания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (i == 1){
    arrays[i][j] = x++;
}
if (j == 1){
    arrays[i][j] = y++;
}
```

заменить на

```
else {
    arrays[i][j] = arrays[i-1][j] + arrays[i][j-1];
}
```

Comment: talex, спасибо ... а я ломал голову часа четыре (((

Answer (score 2):

Зачем себе усложнять жизнь и делать много условий..

```
int n = 6; // К примеру
int[][] a = new int[n][n];

// Заполним первый ряд и колонку единичками
// Либо заполнить весь массив 1
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a[0][i] = 1;
    a[i][0] = 1;
}

// Каждому элементу присваиваем сумму того, что выше и того, что и левее
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
        a[i][j] = a[i-1][j] + a[i][j-1];
```

Comment: entithat, спасибо за помощь... я почему-то не подумал, что можно начиная со второй строки заполнять элементы массива суммируя элементы справа и слева ... отметил ответ ниже, так как он мне показался более оптимальным что-ли

Comment: @YuriiS, право Ваше, всегда пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int size = 6;
        int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];
        // Заполнение первого столбца и строки
        for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        {
             matrix[i][0] = matrix[0][i] = 1;
        }

        // Заполнение оставшейся части матрицы
        for(int row = 1; row < size; row++)
        {
            for(int col = row; col < size; col++)
            {
                matrix[row][col] = matrix[row][col -1] + matrix[row -1][col];
                if( row != col )
                {
                    matrix[col][row] = matrix[row][col];
                }
            }
        }

        // Вывод результата
        for(int row = 0; row < size; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < size; col++)
            {
                System.out.print(" " + matrix[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } 
}
```